# How can i repeatedly save the python output values in a JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list

Hey guys this is probably such an amateur question to ask but how do i constantly list the latency value. As you can see in the Terminal i have several values but they get overwritten for each new value. how do i print all of the new python output values in a list like for example

1. {"Latency": "0.039332s for the calculation"}
2. {"Latency": "0.025932s for the calculation"}
3. {"Latency": "0.032072s for the calculation"}
4. {"Latency": "0.049562s for the calculation"}
   and so on...
   instead of just one
5. {"Latency": "0.039332s for the calculation"} which gets overwritten with each new value

```
from time import sleep
import datetime
import pymongo
import time
import json
# This URL provides connection to the database
uri = blahblah

# initialising pymongo client
client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)

# Database where the records will be saved - reference to the database
db = client.Kostenanalyse

# Accessing the collection "latenz" from the Database
coll = db.latenz

#Defining the Start time
start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
start_time = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
end = time.perf_counter()

# Opens a file to read current temperature
with open(r"/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp") as File:
        ActualTemp = int(File.readline())/float(1000)


def create_info_data()-> dict:
 
 return {
       "CurrentTemp in °C" : ActualTemp,
       "Time when packet was sent" : datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),
       "Sensor reading" : "",
       "Latency" : end,

}

def writeToJSONFile(path, fileName, data):
    filePathNameWExt = './' + path + '/' + fileName + '.json'
    with open(filePathNameWExt, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp)




#While loop 
while True:
    data = create_info_data()

    start = time.perf_counter()

    coll.insert_one(data)

    end = time.perf_counter() - start

    print('{:.6f}s for the calculation'.format(end))
    data = {}
    data['Latency'] = '{:.6f}s for the calculation'.format(end) 
    writeToJSONFile('./','latency',data)

    print(str(start_time) + str(float(ActualTemp)) + 'Wrote data sample {} to collpipection {}'.format(data, 'info'))

    sleep(0.5)
```

[My python code + Terminal + Json file as a screenshot on linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YSTS.png)

Comment: Please post your code as a text

Comment: In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort and submit data to be used to reproduce your problem. While providing an image is helpful, it doesn't allow for reproducing the issue. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Comment: So, what you want is to append to a file and not just rewrite to it. 
Therefore, open the file in `append` mode (ex. `open(fileName, 'a')`). And, then you can modify your func accordingly to add serial number and stuff.

Comment: @Alderven  Mittal I have edited tthe post with my code in it any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open a file with the `w` mode, you will always start writing to it at the beginning of the file. To append to a file, open the file with the `a` mode, this will let you start writing to the end of the file instead:

```py
with open(filePathNameWExt, 'a') as fp:
    # write to fp will not overwrite existing data
```